# How to bind webservice client to specified IP (network interface) with Apache CXF?

Tags: java, networking, jboss, cxf

My problems is: there is a one RHEL default server with 2 NIC configured:

- eth0 with IP 10.100.0.1
- eth1 with IP 10.100.100.1

Also, there is jboss-6.0.0.20101110-CR1 installed on Red Hat, with an EAR deployed on this JBoss, which is a simple servlet listen to incoming data, and, after some processing, application forwards processed data to another web service on another host (for example 10.200.0.1), using Apache CXF framework (such a proxy with some of processing).

Now, configuration issues.

When JBoss need to listen incoming data on eth0, IP **10.100.0.1**, need to be run.sh with "-b" switch: run.sh -b 10.100.0.1, which is simple and clean.

But I want to expand my issue: I want to enforce JBoss to call web service on other host with **10.100.100.1** as source IP for network traffic. How to do it? Is there any switch/property/whatever, which do the job?

Summary:

JBoss binds to eth0 for listen to incoming data on **10.100.0.1** and calls webservice with source IP **10.100.100.1** on **10.200.0.1**.

Please help me, any ideas are really apreciated. I want to avoid any iptables/xinted redirect configuration :-)

Regards,

Mariusz

PS. I've found another, similar issue (but native JBoss WS related...) in my company: one of our software providers has modified JBoss5's jbossws-native-core.jar to force this behavior by adding line:

*bootstrap.setOption("localAddress", new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, 0));*

to NettyClient.java, when localAddress is provided with -D switch and readed by getProperty() method in code. But also I want to avoid any of JBoss components modification...

Answer (score 0):

If JBoss is only listening on one ip, that's all it's going to be able to easily reply with that same ip.  I'd suggest you solve this with routing, not with hacking in java. I presume, because it's already working, that 10.200.0.1 is actually accessible via both eth0 and eth1.

I suggest making it only available via eth1, and then having jboss listen to both interfaces.  Jboss will then happily choose whichever source address is required to get the traffic routed.

You may need some corresponding routing on the remote side, if you had some particular reason you only wanted to listen to a single interface, or, if you can't control that, you could write a servlet filter to drop/deny all traffic arriving with the wrong destination ip.